# Missing dependency packages when installing skype-call-recorder

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I am trying to install `skype-call-recorder`, following [this tutorial](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/12/how-to-record-skype-conversations-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/)

However, I am getting dependency errors:

```
~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i skype-call-recorder-ubuntu_0.8_i386.deb 

(Reading database ... 158095 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace skype-call-recorder 0.8 (using skype-call-recorder-ubuntu_0.8_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement skype-call-recorder ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype-call-recorder:
 skype-call-recorder depends on libqt4-gui (>= 4.3); however:
  Package libqt4-gui is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing skype-call-recorder (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype-call-recorder
```

Then I tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-gui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqt4-gui is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-gui : Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-opengl (= 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.3) but 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-svg (= 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.3) but 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8 is to be installed
              Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.3) but 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Can you tell me what am I missing or how I should install it? My Ubuntu release is 11.10 32-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dpkg -i` to install a `.deb` package does not resolve dependencies and install them as well. You will have to install them by hand with `sudo apt-get install libqtgui4` for example, or you will need to use another tool which does resolve the dependencies, such as running `software-center skype-call-recorder-ubuntu_0.8_i386.deb` which should also resolve the dependencies and pull in the necessary packages.